# PHP scripting to use search engine

Tags: php, google-search-api

I'm making a simple website with a form where a user enters a word and then I take that word and google it using a php script and displaying the results. How would I be able to do this? or where would I get a script to do this?

Comment: Why not simply redirect to the Google result page? I'm fairly sure reusing their results as you want to do is against their Terms of Service.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure reusing their results as you want to do is against their Terms of Service.

Why not simply create a form that redirects to the Google result page? Here is a tutorial on  how.

[Linking to Google Search Results](http://www.googleguide.com/linking.html)

Answer (score 2):

You would look for Google Site Search - http://www.google.com/sitesearch/

Comment: Oh no its not searching my site, it will search the web returning the results. So there would b a form on my page they enter a word then a php script googles it and displays the result on another page. any ideas how to do it?

Comment: @user903794: Please make it clear whether (A)You want to display web search results (B)You want to display only the results that are inside your site.

Comment: A) display the top 3 advert headlines from a web search. how would you go about with a php script?

Answer (score 0):

First, as **quick solution**, you should redirect your users to Google's result page.

When your sript receives the search term, it may

- change spaces to "+" sign,
- append it to the following URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aexample.com+ (change example.com to your domain),
- redirect to it.

Example: http://www.google.com/search?site=&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+banana

Comment: is it possible to manipulate google's result page to only display the top 3 adverts the total number of adverts on the page?

Comment: Why should anyone do that? (If you wanna make a "fake search engine" with displaying only paid ads, you *have* to be more experienced.)

Comment: well thats basically what I need to do so do you know how to do it or point me in the direction I need to be looking?

Comment: I don't add my name to generate more crap on the internet, and also recommend you to look after a more conducive project. Also, if you will build that site, Google will kick your ass just as they discover it.

Comment: so you don't know how to do it no?

Comment: No, **you** don't know what do you want. What do you want is not a Google search on your site, but a simple "search-engine-alike" page, where all the results are paid ads. There are lotsa kinda sites, but they are short-life ones, as Google kicks their asses just as they find them.

Comment: im not bothered if they kick me off when they find it i just want to create 1 and have it up and running to show I was capable of creating it. would you be able to direct me to tutorials/posts to create such a site?